# References for the convergence of gradient-based algorithms for training neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, training, reference-request, convergence, gradient-methods

I'm looking for some good references that give convergence results of training neural networks. I'm decently familiar with works that analyze the convergence of SGD, and, in particular, I really like this paper [Optimization Methods for Large-Scale Machine Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04838). I'm looking for works that talk about the convergence of SGD (or possibly a different gradient-based algorithm) specifically for neural networks.

An example of the type of paper I'm looking for is [Convergence Analysis of Two-layer Neural Networks with ReLU Activation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09886).